# KeyError: 'Column not found: key'

Tags: python, pandas

I want to groupby 'pickup_year' and create a column as Num_trips and reset the Index.

I tried the following code :

```
trips_year=train.groupby(['pickup_year'])['key'].count().reset_index().rename(columns={'key':'Num_Trips'})
trips_year.head()
```

I get the following error:

> KeyError: 'Column not found: key'

Comment: please provide more info

Comment: obviously you have no column namend key in your dataframe

Comment: Can we see your data? or a sample of it

Comment: i dont have an option to upload the dataset

Comment: @jazrael can u please provide me the link to the problem.